# Google Cloud Storage unexpected identifier "storage"

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I found this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/) and this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.0.x/) about uploading files to Google Cloud Storage. I wrote this code:

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage')();
const projectId = 'myapp-cd94d';
const storage = new Storage({
  projectId: projectId,
});

const bucketName = "myapp-cd94d.appspot.com";
const filename = { 'test': 'file'};

var serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json")

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    storageBucket: "myapp-cd94d.appspot.com"
});

var bucket = admin.storage().bucket();

await storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(filename, {
  gzip: true,
  metadata: {
    cacheControl: 'no-cache',
  },
});

console.log(`${filename} uploaded to ${bucketName}.`);
```

I tried to deploy the code and got this error message:

```
await storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(filename, {
      ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Is there something wrong with my first line

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage')();
```

Why are there curly brackets around `Storage`? Am I supposed to replace `{Storage}` with something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why are there curly brackets around Storage? Am I supposed to replace {Storage} with something else?

The curly braces around `Storage` indicate a [deconstructing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring). It allows you to extract multiple values from data stored in objects and Arrays. The example import from the [documentation you shared](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.0.x/) (`const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');`) is correct.

The error message `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` is not saying that it didn't identify `storage`, it's saying that it didn't expect `storage` to be there. The error is due to `await`.

[`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) can only be used in an `async` function. For example:

```
async function myAsyncFunction() {
  let result = await lengthyFunction();

  console.log(result);
}

myAsyncFunction();
```

Try wrapping the bucket upload call inside an `async` function to avoid the error when using `await`.

Comment: I starting writing "Unidentified expectifier" instead of "Unexpected identifier." Maybe a lost handkerchief? :-)

Comment: @ThomasDavidKehoe No worries, happens to the best haha